# Adding onclick to Polygon Location Label in Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygons

I have the following code where I initialize a Polygon with an onclick listener that displays an alert:

```
polygon.location = location;

polygon.locationLabel = new LocationLabel(location, latLng, mapProvider.map);

 google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function(e) {
            alert('hello');
 });
```

This is fine, but displays the alert when I click the Polygon but not the actual Label. How would I add a Listener so that the alert would be displayed just when the label is clicked?

Comment: What is `LocationLabel`?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try with :

```
 textToShow = polygon.locationLabel;
 google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function(e, textToShow) {
       alert(textToShow);
 });
```

Comment: This still only alerts on clicking of the Polygon and not the label itself

Comment: Are you sure polygon.locationLabel contain a value?